# EF Core 2.2 Calling Stored Procedure Returning 0 results

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I can't seem to get any results from my stored procedure.

Here's the code:

```
public JsonResult SearchBudgetRequests(int BudgetRequestNumber, int FiscalYearId)
{
    var result = _db.Search.FromSql($"EXECUTE spSearchGeneral {0}, {1}, {2}", BudgetRequestNumber, _sessionUser.DepartmentId, FiscalYearId)
                .ToList();

    return Json(result);
}
```

I can verify the stored procedure returns data:

[image]

Context:

```
public DbQuery<Search> Search { get; set; }
```

Model class:

```
 public partial class Search
 {
        public int BudgetRequestId { get; set; }
        public string BudgetRequestNumber { get; set; }
        public string RequestStatus { get; set; }
        public string CurrentOwner { get; set; }
        public string ContactUser { get; set; }
        public string BudgetDescription { get; set; }
        public string RequestType { get; set; }
        public string CapsUnits { get; set; }
        public string ObjectCategory { get; set; }
        public string RecurringType { get; set; }
        public string CoreType { get; set; }
        public decimal Expenditure { get; set; }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

**Update:**

Think something is wrong with my stored procedure format, when I traced the call, the query also shows 0 results, here's what the generated query looks like:

```
exec sp_executesql N'EXECUTE spSearchGeneral 0, 1, 2',N'@p0 int,@p1 int,@p2 int',@p0=37124,@p1=1,@p2=2015
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) incorrectly here

```
_db.Search.FromSql($"EXECUTE spSearchGeneral {0}, {1}, {2}", BudgetRequestNumber, _sessionUser.DepartmentId, FiscalYearId)
```

just remove `$`

```
_db.Search.FromSql("EXECUTE spSearchGeneral {0}, {1}, {2}", BudgetRequestNumber, _sessionUser.DepartmentId, FiscalYearId)
```

To use string interpolation correctly:

```
_db.Search.FromSql($"EXECUTE spSearchGeneral {BudgetRequestNumber}, {_sessionUser.DepartmentId}, {FiscalYearId}")
```

Comment: I'd suggest a link to https://cmatskas.com/ef-core-string-interpolation-and-sql-injection/ and an explicit statement in your answer explaining why this is safe from SQL Injection may be helpful.